# How to replace key val in json using shell

Tags: json, shell, replace

sample Json file 
{

```
    "abc":"n",
    "123":"y",
    "atom" :"csv",
```

}

after replaced the json

{

```
    "abc":"try",
    "123":"finish",
    "atom" :"err",
```

}

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

you can use `jq`:

```
jq '."abc"="try" | ."123"="finish" | ."atom"="err"' d.json
```

output :

```
{
  "abc": "try",
  "123": "finish",
  "atom": "err"
}
```

but unfortunately `jq` does not support in-place editing, so you must redirect to a temporary file first and then replace your original file with it, or use `sponge` utility from the more utils package, like that:

```
jq '."abc"="try" | ."123"="finish" | ."atom"="err"' file.json|sponge file.json
```